# How to correctly configure JWT in asp.net core2?

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0, bearer-token

I am trying to apply JSON Web token based auth in my `api` application. the problem is that I am getting invalid token signature every time I am testing my token. moreover, I can't get my request authorized in my controllers and I think it might have something to do with generating the latter.

I posting all relevant code and would highly appreciate if someone can help me.
The source code is derived from github [ASPNETCore2JwtAuthentication](https://github.com/embryologist/ASPNETCore2JwtAuthentication)

**appsettings.json**

```
 "BearerTokens": {
  "Key": "iNivDmHLpUA223sqsfhqGbMRdRj1PVkH",
  "Issuer": "http://localhost/",
  "Audience": "http://localhost/",
  "AccessTokenExpirationMinutes": 2,
  "RefreshTokenExpirationMinutes": 60
},
```

**Startup.cs** / ConfigureServices

```
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                    {
                        options.AddPolicy(CustomRoles.Admin, policy => policy.RequireRole(CustomRoles.Admin));
                        options.AddPolicy(CustomRoles.User, policy => policy.RequireRole(CustomRoles.User));
                        options.AddPolicy(CustomRoles.Editor, policy => policy.RequireRole(CustomRoles.Editor));
                    });


            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie(cfg => 
                { 
                    cfg.SlidingExpiration = true; 
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    cfg.SaveToken = true;
                    cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["BearerTokens:Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["BearerTokens:Audience"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["BearerTokens:Key"])),
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                    };
                    cfg.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                    {
                        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                        {
                            var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger(nameof(JwtBearerEvents));
                            logger.LogError("Authentication failed.", context.Exception);
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        },
                        OnTokenValidated = context =>
                        {
                            var tokenValidatorService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenValidatorService>();
                            return tokenValidatorService.ValidateAsync(context);
                        },
                        OnMessageReceived = context =>
                         {
                             return Task.CompletedTask;
                         },
                        OnChallenge = context =>
                        {
                            var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger(nameof(JwtBearerEvents));
                            logger.LogError("OnChallenge error", context.Error, context.ErrorDescription);
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                });


            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder
                        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200") //Note:  The URL must be specified without a trailing slash (/).
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials());
            });
            services.AddMvc();



**Startup.cs** / Configure


app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc();
```

**TokenStoreService.cs**

```
public async Task<(string accessToken, string refreshToken)> CreateJwtTokens(ApplicationUser user)
{
    var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    var accessTokenExpiresDateTime = now.AddMinutes(_configuration.Value.AccessTokenExpirationMinutes);
    var refreshTokenExpiresDateTime = now.AddMinutes(_configuration.Value.RefreshTokenExpirationMinutes);
    var accessToken = await createAccessTokenAsync(user, accessTokenExpiresDateTime.UtcDateTime).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var refreshToken = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");

    await AddUserTokenAsync(user, refreshToken, accessToken, refreshTokenExpiresDateTime, accessTokenExpiresDateTime).ConfigureAwait(false); // this method is only to store the generated token in the database, irrelevent to the issue.
    await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();


    return (accessToken, refreshToken);
}

 private async Task<string> createAccessTokenAsync(ApplicationUser user, DateTime expires)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                // Unique Id for all Jwt tokes
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                // Issuer
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iss, _configuration.Value.Issuer),
                // Issued at
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToUnixEpochDate().ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                new Claim("DisplayName", user.LastName),
                // to invalidate the cookie
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.SerialNumber, user.SecurityStamp),
                // custom data
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, user.Id.ToString())
            };

            // add roles
            var roles = await _rolesService.FindUserRolesAsync(user.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);
            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.RoleId));
            }

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration.Value.Key));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _configuration.Value.Issuer,
                audience: _configuration.Value.Audience,
                claims: claims,
                notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
                expires: expires,
                signingCredentials: creds);

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }
```

Sample of generated token

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.q-IphSwiOhzDT9upOO4XOvGQVp_NxymcuW4WWuERe2U

[validation link](https://jwt.io/)

Comment: I have write a step by step blog post , may it help you https://mostafizz.wordpress.com/2017/09/30/jwt-token-with-cookie-authentication-in-asp-net-core-2-0/

Comment: The same issue, your code woked for cookies but not JWT

Comment: I hope you did provide key when you tried to validate JWT. I don't see any problem with JWT as such. JWT validation link you provided would always show you invalid signature till you provide it the key you used to generate JWT

Answer (score 0):

so my issue was a bug in my `ITokenValidatorService`which is your customized way of validating your own token.

```
 OnTokenValidated = context =>
                        {
                            var tokenValidatorService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenValidatorService>();
                            return tokenValidatorService.ValidateAsync(context);
                        },
```

The config showed above works just fine

But I still wonder why JWT [validator](https://jwt.io) keeps returning any submitted token as invalid!